# Is it more efficient to launch a spaceplane from a space elevator to a destination on the planet, or to simply fly the plane through the atmosphere?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, space-constructs, aircraft, logistics

Suppose you have a planet that needs to send and receive cargo from a space elevator at the equator. Due to various environmental factors, surface-based transportation is unviable so all cargo needs to be transported via aircraft.

Does it make more sense to haul the cargo planes up the space elevator and launch them back to the planet from space or to have the cargo aircraft solely fly within the atmosphere between the base of the elevator and their destination?

Comment: This is unanswerable without further details. Does it make more sense to take the car or walk to buy bread at the shop down the corner? It depends: are there sidewalks where you can walk? how far is the shop? is the road lit? how is the weather? are you in conditions to walk/drive? do  you have a car? etc...

Comment: If surface-based transport is "not viable," how are you going to build runways for your aircraft? Runways for heavy aircraft are major construction projects.

Comment: aircraft will not be able to fly from geostationary orbit. It would require a different type of vehicle like the space shuttle. Reentry into Earth's atmosphere is not easy and aircraft would just burn up

Comment: @Slarty one does not have to ride every elevator to the top. Just get out part way. That said, even at suborbital speeds, you can't ignore heating, it is just less serious.

Comment: All cargo by air? No ships?  How did they get the economy large enough to get ANY commercial aircraft in the first place. Never mind a space elevator. It seems odd to be worried about house decorations when the house is burning down. Ahh well, beyond scope of qestion

Comment: @Starfish Prime,  yes you are correct. Although no ordinary planes would survive the uncontrolled plunge from space even at 60km up. And even if the plane survived X15 style the range advantage gained would be very limited compared to what might be achieved from orbit.

Comment: @Slarty au contraire! [boost glide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost-glide) or skip-glide trajectories have been considered for [quite some time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silbervogel) and would provide excellent range.

Comment: @Starfish prime, yes again true, although not from 60km up. Oh it looks like the question has been closed...

Answer (score 1):

To expand on another answer, if you have a beanstalk, it not only provides altitude, it provides velocity -- which makes it the obvious answer, as long as your transport craft can handle orbital-class reentry and you don't need to get too far from the equator.

Portions of the elevator below the synchronous height won't provide full orbital velocity for their height, but they will provide a good fraction of it -- enough that, by choosing your height, you can launch to literally anywhere within your crossrange glide capability.  Stay low, you may only go a few hundred kilometers (watch out, reentry may be rough in this case, as the less forward velocity you have, the higher your peak G load because you penetrate deeper at high velocity vs. being able to kill more speed high up where the air is very thin).  Go higher, you get flung further, because you're at a larger fraction of orbital speed.

Now, all of these cases are zero or near-zero fuel consumption; the only energy input is what's used to haul the transport up the beanstalk.  Add significant delta-V (say, half of low orbit velocity) to your transports, and you greatly expand your crossrange -- in the extreme, you can launch from synchronous height, boost still higher to make a relatively cheap plane change, then deorbit for aerobraking and go literally anywhere on the planet's surface, even the poles -- and it will still take less time than subsonic atmospheric flight except in the most extreme cases (polar landings).

Answer (score 1):

**Once in a college economics class a group and I were asked to explain why using one method of drying your hands in a commercial bathroom was better than another. The experience was illuminating.**

And it bears directly on this question. You have the technology to build space elevators, so the technology aspect of the question is materially *irrelevant.* When you ask if it's better to hold the cargo at the top and bring the plane to the cargo or drop the cargo to the planet and use the plane from there, the answer will always (always) be one of *economics.*

If that college experience taught me anything, it's that an analysis like this is never simple. The cost of paper vs. heating air vs. customer preferences... Ugh. What a memory. Because I work for a living, you're going to get a simplified analysis.

Rule #1: Since the cargo must go to the ground anyway, the only question is how to minimize the cost of getting it to the ground at a location that's useful.

Rule #2: I am assuming that the value of the electricity mentioned in #1 below is greater than the cost of lifting the plane to the top of the tower. *I admit that could be a false assumption.* But I doubt it. See #4 below.

**1. It's *profitable* to send the cargo to the surface.**

Your space elevator will certainly use [regenerative braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_braking) to lower the elevator cab. That means you're generating a proverbial boat load of electricity on the way down. Every gram of mass heading to the surface increases the amount of electricity produced, which makes the elevator's overall operation more efficient. It's valuable to send the cargo to the surface. Let's call that value "X."

**2. It's *unprofitable* to send the plane into space.**

On the other hand, you must pay to send that plane into space. Every gram of plane costs you money. There are efficiencies at play here — for example, if the weight of the plane is significantly less than the weight of the platform then the cost of lifting the plane is little different than lifting the platform empty... just as most of the gas in your car is for moving the car, not you... but you're still paying to lift that elevator when you could have left it on the ground and paid nothing. My point is, there will always be a cost, let's call it "Y," and if X > Y then it's *never* the right solution to send the plane into space.

**3. Every time you use that elevator, there's a risk.**

Economics forces us to realize that every use of the elevator bears a risk. In most cases the risk isn't catastrophic. Broken parts, damage or injury due to shifting material, inconvenient lightning strike... sometimes they are catastrophic: the proverbial cable snaps and everything crashes to the ground at terminal velocity. Insurance companies make their money by playing the odds of how frequently risk becomes reality and at what average cost. So long as the average cost over incident time is lower than premiums over the same time they make money. That's your problem, too, and it can be reasonably reflected by modifying the equation from #2. So long as X >= Y it's *always* better to send the cargo to the ground.

**4. That elevator is *really tall.***

Your space elevator is at least [35,786 km tall](https://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2000/ast07sep_1). The Earth's circumference is [40,075 km](https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/features/cosmic/earth_info.html). Think about that. You're hauling that plane *against the full force of gravity* almost the entire circumference of the Earth just to pick up the load. Even if the plane is a glider, you proverbially flew all the way around the Earth at the highest possible expense (full gravity, every moment was straight up) to pick up the load. Here's the real kicker, *in the worst case,* your furthest destination *is only halfway around the world.* That means you lifted the plane the full circumference of the Earth just to fly it half that distance again. 1.5 is never more efficient than 0.5 and most destinations will be less than 0.5. That means X >> Y in all cases.

**5. If there is a benefit, it's only a benefit to the first destination.**

Unless you plan to haul a lot of planes to the top of the tower so that the cargo can be distributed to every location it's expected to go to, and if we ignore all other issues that might make hauling up the plane a problem, it's only a benefit for the first destination. Every destination after that will only ever be launched from the ground. From this perspective, the question becomes whether or not the cargo can be more efficiently distributed from a location other than the base of the tower. But that begs the question, what other considerations put the tower where it is rather than where the cargo needs to go in the first place? *But it is reasonable to suggest that there are conditions that force the tower to be where it is even if it's not where the cargo wants to be.* But I'm not sure it's reasonable to believe that there is only one spot on the planet where the cargo should be. Either way, if that ideal location for the cargo isn't on the other side of the planet, the benefits of using the cargo's mass to generate energy during descent IMO always exceed the cost of moving the cargo on the ground.

**But, is there a way to use the tower to advantage?**

Well... maybe. Ignoring the efficiencies of different lift methods (the tower, a crane, rockets, propellers...) the cost of lifting the plane 10 km is *identical.* More accurately, the energy needed to lift the plane 10 km is the same no matter how you lift it. The only question is what method of getting that energy costs the least. Compared to the cost of lifting the plane 3,500X that distance, I believe the cost difference in methods is irrelevant.

But you could have staging points along the length of the tower that would allow you to place cargo planes at different altitudes, each with its cost to place it there. So long as the profitability of lowering the mass less the cost of lifting the plane vs. the distance the plane needs to travel are *minimized,* (i.e., the profit-to-loss ratio is *maximized*) it's more useful to move a plane up the tower.

Well... kinda.

- I suspect the profitability of dropping the mass to the surface will *always* represent the greatest profit-to-loss ratio.
- The cost of having multiple planes sitting on staging platforms/hangars at various points along the tower is much greater than you might think. When companies buy, for example, a plane at such a large capital expense, they want that expense making money for them every possible second of the day. A plane sitting around waiting for the right profit-to-loss ratio to come around is, in fact, losing money. (BTW, when you're calculating the time the plane is doing useful work, the time it takes to haul it up 35,000 km is a long, wasteful period of time.)
- A plane lifting from the ground will never come even close to 35,000 km in altitude. The average passenger jet cruises at 10-11 km. Heavy cargo planes fly lower than that. it's cheaper for many reasons, one of which is that the increase in circumference when you add another 35,000 km to the planet's radius is *non-trivial.* You obviously get a boost from the velocity of the top of the tower, but you're forced to fly farther, too. I haven't done the math, but I doubt it's in your favor if your destination is anywhere in the hemisphere containing the tower. I doubt it's in your favor regardless the destination.
- A plane that can re-enter the Earth's atmosphere from low orbit is *much more expensive* than a traditional cargo plane. That's obviously ameliorated by how high up on the tower a plane must be depending on that profit-to-loss ratio, but now we're talking about having multiple fleets of planes, each having been optimized for the launch altitude vs. one plane that always launches from the ground and all the economy of scale (like every plane using the same parts) that goes with it.

**TL;DR**

Money, my friend, makes the world go round. And when economics is brought into the mathematics of whether or not it makes sense to haul a plane to the top of a space elevator rather than sending the cargo down, IMO, it never makes sense to send the plane up.

Comment: The part of this about hauling the load the full circumference of the planet against full gravity to get halfway around is just wrong.  See my answer -- well before you get to full synchronous height, you have a combination of altitude and suborbital velocity sufficient to get anywhere on the equator and, with a good transport design, substantially to north or south (several degrees, at least, maybe more if you can design skip reentries).  Also, energy spent hauling the platform up is (mostly) recovered when the platform comes down; only transport/payload mass actually costs.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I read your answer, it was one of the reasons I wrote this one. You premise is false. There is a cost to haul the plane to the height where velocity is a benefit - and you ignored it.

Comment: There is.  There's also a cost for flying the cargo in-atmosphere.  Assuming you're sensible and put a big solar array at your counterweight, the energy to run your elevator has only the long term maintenance cost of the solar array (which doesn't include exorbitant chemical launch costs), plus amortization of the construction cost of the beanstalk, of course.  Then the question becomes one of what your atmospheric transports cost to build and operate.  Which can vary wildly in a colony situation, depending what tech the colonists brought or chose to build.

Comment: @ZeissIkon We need to agree to disagree. I consider what you just said to be as wrong as you believe my answer to be. I can always engineer the descent to provide a benefit and can never engineer the ascent to be anything but a detriment. And I have a tough time believing that hauling the plane 35,000 km just to start its journey no matter what the conditions will ever be beneficial compared to the cost of flying it from the ground. Then there's the issue that it's a benefit only to the first destination. That's worth adding to my answer.

Comment: Hey @ZeissIkon... just to be sure, comments aren't for arguing over whose answer is better. This discussion kinda feels that way. I've not voted either way for your answer (I rarely do when I answer a question).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistaken understanding of how far the top of a space elevator is. Geosynchronous Orbit is as far away as an entire trip around the planet, and it's literally all uphill.

The energy required to get a ton up to geosync is roughly equivalent to an hour and a half of flight time for a 747.

What you have to consider here is whether or not you can re-coup the cost of dropping things from the space elevator in order to move things back up again. When designing normal elevators, it's a primary energy-saving requirement that you use the energy of lowering elevators in order to move other elevators up.

Normally, counterweights are used to store potential energy so that the motors aren't actually required to lift the objects, they just have to lower the counterweight on one side and pull the elevator up on the other. Expensive systems will actually use pulley systems to balance out the weight of multiple elevators, and use a transmission to compensate for the passenger weight, too.

For a space elevator, it would be even more important to make use of the potential energy of the falling cargo to lift other cargo up. I'm sure that there would be some cases where someone reached the anchor station of the space elevator and needed to take an emergency shuttle to the surface, but this would not be standard practice.

Even if you are just lifting them to the edge of space, you're actually better off using that energy to power a catapult system that lifted the jets to a few miles up and left them at cruising velocity.

Comment: "For a space elevator, it would be even more important to make use of the potential energy of the falling cargo to lift other cargo up.": this really isn't feasible even in theory, at least on Earth. The energy is generated at the crawler, which is clinging to a tether many thousands of km away from anywhere. The tether itself is just on the edge of being mechanically feasible, and can't carry 100 thousand km of power transmission cable as well as its payload. Power transmission from the ground to the climber is expected to be 0.5% to 2% efficient, the reverse would be worse.

Comment: And yes, *some* carbon nanotubes are electrically conductive, and power transmission cables *can* be made from them. An elevator cable will have to be designed for strength and durability over all other factors, however. Requiring it to *also* provide two conductive paths to carry electrical power all the way along its length to a climber is not realistic.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is that launching from a space elevator is a million times more effective than launching your space plane from earth.

The main reason we haven't colonized Mars or the moon is because of the cost to get up there. It isn't easy break out of the earth gravity well. The energy cost of would too much for regular trips to be practical, the hole point of a space elevator is that it would by pass our gravity well, there by lowering the cost of space travel.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question - the OP is asking about whether on-planet cargo deliveries should take off from the ground or be launched from some higher point on the space elevator.  Movement of cargo to other planets is not under discussion.

Comment: Have you not been paying attention to what I wrote. ObviouslyA cargo space plane would have to break Through the gravity wellIf it was coming from the planet so it should then be launched from the space Elevator.